# How to receive data from buildin function of another class in another module

Tags: function, class, tkinter, module, return

I am programming a case manager (administration system). To build it constructively, I program in separate `modules` to keep an overview. Some modules contain a `class-object` where I build an small search engine including its own `functions`. The main program is the case form itself. Obviously, when the search engine finds an entry, it should fill in the case form. I am able to call the search engine (and the search engine works to), however I don't know how to return the results back to the main program/case form/`module`.

[To give you a picture, I have added a image of the GUI, so you can see the case form and the search engine (which is a different `module` and `class` (inheriting `tk.Toplevel`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrbsW.jpg)

The relevant code (case_form/main program):

```
import ReferenceSearch as rs #Own module

def search_ref(self):
    #Function to call search engine
        
    search_engine = rs.ReferenceSearch(self, self.csv_file.get(), self.references_list)
    
    #Reveive data from search_engine and show it in case_form
    self.title_var.set(search_engine) #DOES NOT WORK BECAUSE search_engine IS THE ACTUAL ENGINE NOT THE 
    DATA returned from its buildin function
```

Relevant code in ReferenceSearch module:

```
class ReferenceSearch(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, csv_file,references_list=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.csv_file = csv_file
        self.references_list = references_list

        self.ref_search_entry = ttk.Entry(self.search_frame)
        self.search_but = tk.Button(self.search_frame,
                                        text=" Search ",
                                        command=lambda:self.search_for_ref(self.ref_search_entry.get())


     def search_for_ref(self, reference, csv_file="Cases.csv"):
        #Function to read specific entry by reference
        
        if reference in self.references_list:
            with open(csv_file, "r", newline="") as file:
                reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="|")
                
                for entry in reader:
                    if reference == entry["Reference"]:
                        
                        data = entry["Title"] #By example
            return data
```

How do I receive the data from the buildin `function` of the ReferenceSearch `class` and use it in the main `module` the `case_form`?

Keep in mind that the ReferenceSearch `module` is calling this `function` when the search `button` is pressed (and not the case_form `module`). However, the data is needed in the case_form `module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ReferenceSearch` module contents to:

```py
class ReferenceSearch(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, csv_file,references_list=[]):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = ""
        self.parent = parent
        self.csv_file = csv_file
        self.references_list = references_list

        self.ref_search_entry = ttk.Entry(self.search_frame)
        self.search_but = tk.Button(self.search_frame,
                                        text=" Search ",
                                        command=lambda:self.search_for_ref(self.ref_search_entry.get())


     def search_for_ref(self, reference, csv_file="Cases.csv"):
        #Function to read specific entry by reference
        
        if reference in self.references_list:
            with open(csv_file, "r", newline="") as file:
                reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="|")
                
                for entry in reader:
                    if reference == entry["Reference"]:
                        
                        data = entry["Title"] #By example
            self.parent.title_var.set(data)
```

and case_form contents to:

```py
import ReferenceSearch as rs

def search_ref(self):
    #Function to call search engine
        
    search_engine = rs.ReferenceSearch(self, self.csv_file.get(), self.references_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, now I am able receive the date from the other module. However, timing is everything. With this solution, I already receive the data when starting the search_engine and is not updated when the actual search is performed...

Comment: @Lawrence i edited the code in my answer, it should do what what you want now !

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for this solution via parent.